# Best way to configure environment variables for Tomcat

Tags: linux, tomcat, environment-variables

I'm having a service file for Tomcat in the directory /etc/systemd/system and I have kept some environment file in that service file. also the file $TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh contains some other environment variables.

Now I'm planning to move all the environment variables into one file (tomcat service file or setenv.sh file).

kindly help me, which file is the best to have the environment variables? whether service file or setenv.sh file?

Answer (score 0):

Well, `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` file should be executed when the Tomcat is started. Putting variables there should be fine. I sometimes put them directly in `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh` and never had any problem.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. one more question, the service file will run first right? so it will be export the envs before setenv.sh file executed right?